# TypeScript: undefined is not assignable to type 'boolean | ConnectionOptions | undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, postgresql, express

I am working with the below code-block, I built it a couple of months ago in JavaScript, but las week I decided to start learning TypeScript. I cant seem to find how to properly defined the data types. Does any one have any hints or resources that can aid me to solve this issue?

---

this is the exact error message:

src/utils/pool.ts:5:5 - error TS2322: Type '"" | { rejectUnauthorized: false; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean | ConnectionOptions | undefined'.
Type '""' is not assignable to type 'boolean | ConnectionOptions | undefined'.

5     ssl: process.env.PGSSLMODE && { rejectUnauthorized: false },

---

Thanks so much!

```
import { Pool, PoolConfig } from 'pg';


 export const pool = new Pool({
      connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
      ssl: process.env.PGSSLMODE && { rejectUnauthorized: false },

    })

 pool.on('connect', ()=> console.log('Postgres connected'))
```

Comment: can you share the code for the Pool class to better answer your question. From what the error indicates seems like you are using a string where a type 'boolean | ConnectionOptions | undefined' is expected

Comment: hey Atik, the Pool is not a class. it is an npm package npm i @types/pg.   

However it seems to work when I remove the process.env.PGSSLMODE && .

Comment: my bad didn't see the path. I have never used this package though from the look of it you need to check the value of process.env.PGSSLMode if I interpret the error correctly seems like it is empty string which is in this shortcircuit syntax is falsey and there for ssl is assigned the value of string when it should be 'boolean | ConnectionOptions | undefined'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what the error indicates seems like you are using a string where a type 'boolean | ConnectionOptions | undefined' is expected
Try this syntax instead

```js
import { Pool, PoolConfig } from 'pg';


 export const pool = new Pool({
      connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
      ...( process.env.PGSSLMODE ? {ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }} : {}),
    })

 pool.on('connect', ()=> console.log('Postgres connected'))
```

Comment: This really should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Naveen Atik, thank you so much! This works! However do you think you can give me a quick run down of the syntax, this would help me to better learn TS moving forward. Again thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry for the late response I was in vacation actually still am.
sure so the syntax is basically conditionally spreading an object
if PGSSLMODE flag is truthy it will spread following object 
`{ ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }}`
which results in adding ssl property to the options object with value `{ rejectUnauthorized: false}`
if it is not provided or falsey spread an empty object which would not add any unexpected property to the options object hence typescript won't complain.

Answer (score 0):

If you interpret the log output it clearly states there is an issue is with the type which is expected and the type which you have declared.

The Expected type is,
**boolean** or **ConnectionOptions** or **undefined**.

The Given type is,
**""** or **{ rejectUnauthorized: false; }** or **undefined**

You need to assign a variable of the appropriate type or update the type of currently assigned variable.